# Unable to get data from mongo collection while configured two databases - mongotemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have configured two db's using

Below is the configuration file that I have used

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "empMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate empMongoTemplate(@Qualifier("empFactory") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory)
        throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "attendMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate attendMongoTemplate(@Qualifier("attendFactory") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory)
        throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "empProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb.emp")
public MongoProperties empProperties() throws Exception {
    return new MongoProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "attendProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb.attend")
public MongoProperties attendProperties() throws Exception {
    return new MongoProperties();
}

@Bean("empFactory")
@Primary
public MongoDbFactory empFactory(@Qualifier("empProperties") MongoProperties mongoProperties)
        throws Exception {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(mongoProperties.getUri());
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(uri);
}

@Bean("attendFactory")
public MongoDbFactory attendFactory(@Qualifier("attendProperties") MongoProperties mongoProperties)
        throws Exception {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(mongoProperties.getUri());
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(uri);
}
```

It's always searching for the collection and its documents in `@Primary` database. How can I fetch the documents from an collection from another database? Is there any way to define `@Primary` dynamically?